# PHP preg_replace() regex

Tags: php

I am getting a dynamic value in the following format, can anyone help me how to get rid of extra chars using preg_replace()?

```
case1)  $string='""14""';  
case2)  $string='""string1""';  
case3)  $string='"[\"string1\", \"string2\"]"';  
case4) $string='"[\"string1\", \"string21\", \"string3\"]"';
```

here i want to get rid of only " [ \ ] but not comma ',', so if it is one string i will get only double quotes but if it is more than one i will get in the farm comma separated.

i need following output.
    case1)  14
    case2)  string1
    case3)  string1,string2
    case4)  string1,string21,string3

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: looks like mangled json... wouldn't you be better off fixing whatever's generating this?

Comment: Can you please added expected output for each given input?

Comment: I need the following out put.

Comment: sorry i just edited for the output that i need

Comment: @user1642408: Pay attention to MarcB's comment: it does look a lot like you're attempting to parse JSON data using regex. Try `var_dump(json_decode($string));` in case 4, for example... you might be surprized at how easy things can be

Comment: well it's not a json data by name, it's a array output when i formatted the out put of the ruby hash.

Comment: cool, i got it, preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9,s]/", "", $string)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this looks like mangled JSON.  But just calling json_decode on it won't work because of the extra quotes around the string.  Try stripping them like this:

```
$str = substr($str, 1, -1);
$vals = json_decode($str);
print_r($vals);
```

if you really want it formatted exactly as you mentioned in your question, you can continue

```
$str = implode(',', $vals);
print_r($str);
```